# How to disable Tab component (Carbon Design System) using React

Tags: reactjs

I'm working with React.js and Carbon as Design System. I have a `Tabs` component with multiple `Tab` and I need to disable one of them if a condition is not satisfied.
I have tried to disable using the carbon class

`className="bx--tabs__nav-item--disabled"`

and also with prop `disabled={true}`but none of them works

There is some different way to disable the Tab element?? I know that avoid the onclick event works, but is no the prettiest way.
This is the code of the Tabs component.

```
            <Tabs
              tabContentClassName="tab-content"
              className="tabs element-header__tabs"
            >
              <Tab
                onClick={(e) =>
                  onclickHandler(e)
                }
                label="tab 1"
              />
              <Tab
                onClick={(e) =>
                  onclickHandler(e)
                  )
                }
                label="tab 2"
              />
             <Tab
                disabled={true}
                onClick={(e) =>
                  onclickHandler(e)
                  )
                }
                label="tab 3"
              />
            </Tabs>
```

Comment: hi based on there tabs and tab soure file they do not provide the tab disabled option.
try antdesign components this is better then carbon...

Comment: If library doesn't provide such props, you could always create a wrapper over the Tab component, provide disabled prop --> change onClickHandler --> pass rest of the props as it is. This way you will get the functionality you want in the way you want.

Comment: Hi what version of carbon-components-react are you using?

Comment: Hi! I´m using v9

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who stumbles across this...

```
disable={true}
```

Now works in the current version of Carbon Tabs. I'm not sure if it didn't work before but it does now...

https://www.carbondesignsystem.com/components/tabs/code